# How to upload many iPhone photo albums to iPhoto, Picasa or Google+?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photos, data-transfer, picasa

I'm back from trip to Egypt with 1600 pics on my iPhone. To maintain some coherence and not to lose track of everything I was seeing, I created daily or place specific folders on the iPhone.

I can go back and use the iPhone as guidance for manual album creation, but if I could just grab these albums would save a ton on time.

Is there any way to transfer these albums (not just the camera roll) to iPhoto, Picasa or Google+?

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point you can export the photos into iPhoto and create events defined by date. You can then [split the event](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/photos/iphoto08.html#split) as necessary to break out specific locations. Or use tags and smart albums to create subsets of photos for specific locations.